# Opening a second fancybox Within another fancybox!

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Hey! I'm having trouble with my fancyboxes!

I am launching a form within a fancybox. Normally, its opened by fancybox in a iframe mode *(since it's being launched as a widget from other domains)*. Within this iframe, i am opening a second fancybox to display validation errors. **All this - works good.**

**But**, if a user visists the url to the form - i need the form to be displayed within a fancybox thats calling the form with type:inline. This is where the second fancybox fails, instead of popping out, over the parent fancybox, it replaces it - and my form disappears.

So... **how do i launch multiple instances of fancybox?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The bad news is, fancybox is a single-instance script. On page load it creates all overlay DIVs. All links and other elements bound with fancybox will just re-use these overlays. Making fancybox handle multiple instances would require a more or less bigger overwrite of the script.

Comment: Thats a big let down! :( I love the simplicity with fancybox, but i guess it comes with a price... I'll guess i could switch the validationmessages to another lightbox solution. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Why not just display validation errors next to the form fields or as a tooltip?

Comment: Well, a tooltip would work, but we require rather much focus on the message, that contains more information than a validation message. I wasn't being completely honest when i said that this was a form. It's a booking module with feedback message. So the normal validation text-messages won't work very well either. Any who, i solved it with another clean popup. It works well. It's actually better than using "double" fancybox popups, which looked a little bloated. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. For feedback message, you can open another url using window.open(). It will just give look of popup. But it'll be a compact window, instead of fancybox / dialog-box type popup.

Answer (score 8):

I achieved this by using afterClose, and re-opening my previous fancybox

```
   $('#modal-2-button').fancybox({
    afterClose: function () {
        $.fancybox($('#modal-1-button'), { maxWidth: 810 });
    }
});
```

This fires when you close modal 2 and it re-opens modal 1.

Answer (score 1):

From a usability and design perspective you should never even attempt this, since it is a sure fire way of creating a horrible user experience. This is why most modal box frameworks do not support it.

In general when you run in to things that are not supported, whether this be by the browser or by a well known library, stop and think if there is a reason for the missing support, and more often than not you will realize that the missing support is by design.

Comment: Well, i both agree and disagree. It works good for our more complexed scenario. Read my comment above.. but yeah. for a simple form, normal validation messages would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do this by using the `beforeClose` callback.

Basically, before the window closes, set a timeout function to open the other window and return false in the callback to prevent Fancybox from closing the window.

```
$.fancybox( $secondWindow, {
  beforeClose : function() {
    // Set timeout to open the other Fancybox window.
    setTimeout(function() {
      $.fancybox( $firstWindow );
    }, 10);

    // Return false to prevent the Fancybox from closing.
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this if you open first fancybox with iframe:

```
//popup product details in product list
$('.AT3PLPopUpButton').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = $(event.target);
    var elAT3Product = $(target.closest(".AT3Product"));
    var productId = elAT3Product.attr('data-productid');
    $.fancybox({
        width: '80%',
        height: '80%',
        href: '/desktopmodules/atena3/productdetails.aspx?productid=' + productId,
        type: 'iframe',
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect: 'none',
        autosize    : true
    });
});
```