# How to place a fancy box inside another fancy box

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I want to create a popup within a popup.

I have a thumbnail image and when I click on it, it popup with large image using fancy box. Now I want in such a ways that, when I hover over a point in the large image it should popup another image over it.

How to make this possible. If anyone have example with a link then it would be more helpful.

Can we place a fancy box indside another fancy box.

Comment: google first before you create a question [Opening a second fancybox Within another fancybox!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880245/opening-a-second-fancybox-within-another-fancybox)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a popup within another popup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734358/how-to-create-a-popup-within-another-popup)

Comment: why are you repeating the same question?